# What is the meaning of this regex expression?

Tags: python, regex, validation

I am doing a project based on Validation on a website that teaches python(learnstreet.com).
A requirement of the project is that regex must be used to validate the various fields entered by the user.

First part of the project is username validation. The constraints defined by the website for a username are :

> ```
>                Method 1 - Username Validation
> ```
>
> Returns True if the username provided
>   is valid, and False otherwise. A username is valid if it is at least 5
>   characters long and has no spaces nor special (e.g. non alphanumeric)
>   characters.

My solution is incorrect. The website provided me following regex expression for username validation :

`^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$` .

What does the `+$` in this expression indicate?

Also, isn't this incorrect given that username must not have any non-numeric characters, and this expression includes an underscore in the set ?

Comment: `^` and `$` are anchors for denoting the start and end of a regex.  `[]` is a character class.  `+` denotes 1 or more characters.

Comment: Why not `len(username) >= 5 and username.isalpha()`?

Comment: @devnull Thanks that was quick! Also , in that case how does the above regex differ from ^\w+$. This was the regex I submitted in my solution  that was marked as incorrect.

Comment: @VineetKaushik If you want to ensure that the length is at least `5`, then say `{5,}` instead of `+` in your regex.

Comment: @devnull Athough I did use a condition to check the length of the username, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically breaking this all down you've got this regex string:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$
```

The first clause is `^`, which in this context simply denotes the start of a string.

The second clause is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` which denotes a series of one or more (`+`) characters in the set `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, which means any lower case(`a-z`), upper case(`A-Z`), or numerical (`0-9`) characters as well as underscores (`_`).

The final clause is `$`, which in this context simply denotes the end of a string.

That said, you really should use regex as little as possible. I would personally suggest solving this problem with a set intersection.

```
import string
# First, define all the acceptable characters
acceptable = set(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '_'))
def is_valid(username):
    return len(username) >= 5 and set(username).issubset(acceptable)
```

The reason I prefer this approach is because regex is in general a very brittle and often slow approach. I thought that it would be slower, but it turns out that the regex solution here is actually significantly faster (about a factor of 2.5) than the set approach, but I still feel that the flexibility and maintainability of the set code make it a better overall solution.

However, looking at Blender's solutions, though it's not quite as flexible gets around both of these problems. Totally readable, and actually about a factor of three faster than the regex solution.

Blender's solutions posted for convenience:

```
def is_valid(username):
    return len(username) >= 5 and username.replace('_', '').isalpha()
```

Comment: And why must one use regex as little as possible?

Comment: @VineetKaushik regex often matches things you don't expect to, and breaks in strange ways. Not to mention that editing it to do things that are extremely intuitive can be a huge hassle.

Comment: I see your point. By the way what is the difference between the regex given by the website and this one : `^\w+$` . This was the regex I used in my solution, which is wrong according to the website.

Comment: @VineetKaushik Another example of regex's brittleness. There's no real difference in python, but the definition of `\w` actually changes between implementations. In some regex's for instance `_` is not included in the `\w` set.

Comment: Oh! Learned much from this answer . Thanks a lot!

Comment: `len(username) >= 5 and username.replace('_', '').isalpha()` is more readable, IMO. Also, `string.letters` is locale-dependent, so you should use `string.ascii_letters` instead.

Comment: @Blender Thanks for the tips! My original thought was that letters would be better since different locales should have different allowable characters, but switched for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: "In some regex's for instance _ is not included in the \w set." Could you give an example of such a regex?

Comment: @Jerry Vim regex is one example, but in general if the regex is not based on Perl's regex (admittedly these tend to be pretty niche), the `_` character is not included. Decently prevalent in proprietary cases. MATLAB's \w only recently added the _ character, and I believe LabView still lacks it.

Answer (score 3):

`^` is a beginning of line anchor and will match only at the beginning of a line.

`$` is an end of line anchor and will match only at the end of a line.

`[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is a character class that accepts letters, numbers and underscore.

`+` is a quantifier that means 1 or more times the previous character or group.

`[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` will thus match at least 1 letter, number or underscore.

---

I would personally use:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}$
```

For the validation since it also takes into consideration that there's a minimum of 5 characters in the username.

`{n,m}` is a variable quantifier with minimum repeats of `n` and maximum repeats of `m`. If `n` is omitted, it is equivalent to 0 up to `m` times. If `m` is omitted, it is equivalent to `n` minimum repeats up to infinite repeats.

`{5,}` thus means at least 5 repeats.

I wouldn't use the underscore because I do consider it a special character, but I guess that's something which could be considered subjective.

As a mention, the `\w` is called a word character in regex, which is roughly equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and which might have been the site's meaning.

Answer (score 0):

### Your regex does the following

`^` asserts position at the beginning of the string

`[a-zA-Z0-9_]` this will match any letter, number or the symbol `_`.

Since a `+` quantifier follows the character class (`[...]`) above, it means match the character class **between ONE and UNLIMITED times, giving back as needed (greedy)**

`$` then asserts position at the end of the string.